# Python: using dictionaries in conjunction with input

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I am writing a fairly simple text adventure. One function is the eat function, allowing you to eat an object in your inventory and gain hunger. The player inputs the name of the object they wish to eat, and then they gain 
hunger based on the foodvalue of the object. It doesn't seem to work, though.

```
food = ("Bread")
Bread = {"name": "Bread", "foodvalue": 10}
inv = []
inv.append("Bread")
def eat():
    global hunger
    print(*inv,sep='\n')
    print("Eat which item?")
    eatitem = input("> ")
    if eatitem in food and eatitem in inv:  
        hunger = hunger + eatitem["foodvalue"]
        inv.remove(eatitem)
        print("Yum.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

edit: hunger goes down once per turn and when reaching zero you starve. So by eating, you increase your hunger.

Comment: What is happening, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: `eatitem` is a string not  dict, what do you think `eatitem["foodvalue"]` is going to do?

Comment: Not related to the code, but I wondered if this was on purpose or perhaps English is not your first language: generally one would say that eating reduces hunger, rather than increasing it.

Comment: Lets say the user types in "Bread". The value of eatitem is now Bread and so i thought that eatitem["foodvalue"] would become Bread["foodvalue"].

Comment: @perero you probably meant to add the object to the inventory list rather than the string. Look at my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put **the object** in the inventory (`inv`) and look for it using it's `name` key:

```
food = ("Bread")
Bread = {"name": "Bread", "foodvalue": 10}
inv = []
# put the object (dict) in the inventory, not the string
inv.append(Bread)
```

And later on:

```
eatitem = input("> ")
# iterate all items
for item in inv:
    # look for item in 'inv'
    if item['name'] == eatitem:
        # gain item's 'food value'
        hunger = hunger + item["foodvalue"]
        inv.remove(item)
        print("Yum.")
        time.sleep(1)
        # stop the loop to consume a single item instead of all items
        break
```

As Hugh Bothwell suggested in comments, if what you need is to find the food by it's name, you can use a dictionary structure such as:

```
foods = {"Bread": {"foodvalue": 10, ...}}
```

where under any key there is a list of properties the food has.

This will enable you to access a food and it's properties directly:

```
foods['Bread']['foodvalue'] # 10
```

Comment: This will not work, because in `inv` are strings (`'Bread'`) but not the object `Bread`.

Comment: I would suggest inverting the food structure, something like `foodvalues = {"Bread": 10, "Apple": 6}` would be significantly easier to use.

Comment: @HughBothwell actually something like `{"Bread": {"foodvalue": 10, ...}}` would be more extensible.

Answer (score 0):

eatitem is the user's input. "foodvalue" is a key in your dictionary, Bread. You want:

```
hunger = hunger + Bread["foodvalue"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`eatitem` is a string (`'Bread'`), but you want eatitem to be the object `Bread`. There a few ways to archieve that (for example you could evaluate the string the user entered, but this is.. not good.), I'll outline one here:

```
food = {"Bread"} # changed to a set
Bread = {"name" : "Bread", "foodvalue" : 10}
items = { "Bread" : Bread }

[...]

def eat()
    global hunger 
    print(*inv,sep='\n')
    print("Eat which item?")
    eatitem_input = input("> ")
    eatitem = items[eatitem_input]
    if eatitem in food and eatitem in inv:  
        hunger = hunger + eatitem["foodvalue"]
        inv.remove(eatitem)
        print("Yum.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

This could still be improved by use of classes (or maybe [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) ). Also it may be a good idea to split the program in one Input/Output part and one "Engine part".